# открыть файл док в ворде

Tags: php

в php формирую

```
<?php
    $document->save($filename); //имя заполненного шаблона для сохранения
    header('Content-type:application/msword');
    header('Content-Disposition:attachment;filename='.$filename);?>
```

но почему-то сформированный документ не открывается

Comment: Вместо этого `header('Content-type:application/msword');` это `header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');` попробуйте

Comment: Хотя наврядли. У вас скорее что-то с заголовками. [Вот](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11476058/auto-download-the-file-attachment-using-php-word) также посмотрите, может поможет. Бежать надо, так бы у себя посмотрел — более точно ответил.